# Python - Manage errors message (email sending)

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to print a message when there's no error during the shipping of the email and doing an action if there's an error.

I gave it a try but nothing worked, the error message stop everything.

How hide the error message and replace it with my own and keep with an action.

```
 import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'azerty@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'TEST'
mail.Body = 'Hello'


mail.Send()

try :
    print("mail sent")

except BaseException as e:
    print("mail not sent")
    fonction()
```

Comment: Your try is only around the print call, so it'll only catch errors thrown by the print call.

Comment: `mail.Send()` should be in the try block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need write the code you want to test inside `try` block. And for your message printing problem you can try the `else` block of `try-except`. `else` block executes if there is no error in `try` block. So try this:

```
import win32com.client as win32

try :
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'azerty@gmail.com'
    mail.Subject = 'TEST'
    mail.Body = 'Hello'
    mail.Send()

except BaseException as e:
    print("mail not sent")
    fonction()
else:
    # this part is executed if there is no error
    print("mail sent")
```